# OffsetDateTime time is changing zone offset

Tags: java, scala, datetime, java-time

So I have a snippet of code that should basically take in a date-time string and return it in EXACTLY the same format

```
val dateString = "2016-01-01T01:30:55.000+00:00"
println("before: " + dateString)
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS+hh:mm")
val date = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString)
println("after: " + date.format(formatter))
```

However, when I try to re-convert it to a string, I'm getting a different offset!

```
before: 2016-01-01T01:30:55.000+00:00
after:  2016-01-01T01:30:55.000+01:30
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The `+hh:mm` is not the correct format for a time-zone offset. You should use `XXX` instead, as per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

The default DateTimeFormatter for `OffsetDateTime.parse(CharSequence text)`is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss+hh:mm` (without ".SSS").

So I think your error is there.

Pass the `formatter` variable as the 2nd parameter of your method and it should work.

Comment: So the issue there is that if I had the +hh:mm it won't read the .SSS, and then I'm technically losing data. Is there no way to hold on to both values?